# How to call .js from Modal popup in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have a .js file for Modal popup, but i cann't call it.
Here is my code in cshtml Modal TO call modal.js

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render(ACHelper.PathFolder() + "Modal.js?d=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"))
}
```

Comment: You dont really detail when the MVC code would want to do this but ... .js is Browser (Client) side. MVC is Server Side. You must somehow signal to the browser to call you js. Something like SignalR might help.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function from your .js file? or render your .js file?

if calling a function:
im expecting your Scripts.Render called/placed under your layout.
and call your function in modal open callback.

if rendering your .js file:
how about add them to your bundle or create a bundle then load them base on controller or path?

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey Sapitan. i just remove "@section secript {"  and  "}". It's working